# Splash screen missing background image on restart/shutdown

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, shutdown, plymouth, desktop-background

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04.2, Xenial Xerus, on my laptop.
I've successfully changed the splash screen background image following these instructions ... https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?t=71093&s=06a2070eb2371cb7a1c272eecbcc9c8b&p=395713&viewfull=1#post395713 ... posted by 2muchcoffeeman on Nov 26th 2016, 06:15 AM.

After applying the latest software updates I am experiencing a white background behind the splash screen on shutdown. The chosen image remains visible during the login process.  I am guessing this issue is related to latest software updates but do not know how to verify.

I've found various posts suggesting the issue may be related to Plymouth but nothing definitive.  I do not know enough about Plymouth to tinker.

Splash.qml is pointing to the correct image:
Image {
    id: root
    source: "../components/artwork/background.png"

Thanks, in advance, for your assistance.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to [edit] your post to clarify which instructions you followed? At this moment I'm finding both https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?t=71093&s=06a2070eb2371cb7a1c272eecbcc9c8b&p=395713&viewfull=1#post395713 and https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?t=71093&p=395714&viewfull=1#post395714 Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @Elder Geek - thank you for you response.  Original post edited identifying specific directions followed.

Comment: Comment by [U Hertlein](https://askubuntu.com/users/740158/u-hertlein)

FWIW I'm seeing the same problem on Kubuntu 16.04.3. From a logged in session:

    Logout/Restart/Shutdown: cancel dialog is on top of a white background
    Lock: no problem